# Weird behaviour - jQuery .html() causes line breaks to be lost in <pre> elements in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, pre

I have some `pre` elements formatted with line breaks like this:

```
<pre id="code1">Some
formatted
code</pre>

<pre id="code2">Some more
formatted
code</pre>
```

If I apply the following to the first `pre` element:

```
$('#code1').html($('#code1').html());
```

In IE8, this causes the line breaks to be lost and it comes out like this:

```
Some formatted code

Some more
formatted
code
```

In Chrome, the jQuery above has no effect as you would expect.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6mkAa/

Does anyone know what causes this weird behaviour in IE? I would like to edit the content of my `pre` elements without the formatting being lost in the process.

Comment: Two things: (I) and (E)... that about says it all.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `.text()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/6mkAa/6/

```
$('#code1').text($('#code1').text());
```

Comment: This works but loses any HTML I have inside the `pre` element (code colouring etc).

Comment: Yeah you have to do whitespace normalization by hand then. I could do it later if I have time

Answer (score 0):

This issue with IE8 because,
Jquery html() method uses the browser's innerHTML property. Some browsers may not return HTML that exactly replicates the HTML source in an original document. For example, Internet Explorer sometimes leaves off the quotes around attribute values if they contain only alphanumeric characters.

you can use like this

```
$("#code1").innerHTML($("#code1").html())
```